Enabling and configuring csrf for spring boot 3.2 with custom front-end client defined in formLogin().loginPage()
I am trying to properly configure and enable csrf for my springboot application with react frontend. I would like to know how do I set the XSRF-TOKEN in the cookie before I make a post call to the backend /login endpoint supplied by spring boot.
I have the following springboot Security Config:-
     @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain authenticationSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      return http.csrf(csrf-> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
              .cors(cfg -> cfg.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
              .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("http://localhost:3001/login")
                      .loginProcessingUrl("/login"))
              .authorizeHttpRequests(httpcfg -> httpcfg.anyRequest().authenticated())
              .build();
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

      CorsConfigurationSource corsSrc =  new CorsConfigurationSource() {
          @Override
          public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
              CorsConfiguration ccfg = new CorsConfiguration();
              ccfg.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3001"));
              ccfg.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")); // Allow specific HTTP methods
              ccfg.setAllowedHeaders(List.of(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "X-XSRF-TOKEN", "x-xsrf-token"));
              ccfg.setAllowCredentials(true);
              return ccfg;
          }
      };

      return corsSrc;
  }

Following react function invoked during form submit.
function login(loginRequest)
    {
        const SAMPLE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/login"; 
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include", 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
              
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                username: loginRequest.username,
                password: loginRequest.password,
                _csrf: Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
              }),
        }; 

        fetch(SAMPLE_URL , requestOptions)
            .then(res => {
                if(res.ok)
                {
                    navigate("/app/welcome"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(res); 
                }
            })
    }

Behavior: The behavior that I observed is: One my first click on login, the _csrf token is undefined and my POST request to backend http://localhost:8080/login endpoint fails but the cookie is populated with XSRF-TOKEN. The second click to login succeeds where the _csrf token is present.
Workaround: One workaround that I found was to hit the http://localhost:8080/login endpoint from front-end and wait for the redirection to happen to http://localhost:3001/login and have the cookie populated so you are ready to click the login button on front end with the populated XSRF-TOKEN.
Research: Looking for many ways on the internet. A most common solution would be to expose the CSRFToken via a @GetMapping("/csrf") endpoint and invoke the endpoint by making a GET request before making a POST call to the backend (http://localhost:8080/login).
Goal: I would like to research and arrive at an accurate solution by ensuring that I have the cookie populated before I make the POST call to http://localhost:8080/login endpoint so that I don't have to face the trouble of _csrf being undefined and making sure that I don't expose the csrf token via some GET endpoint.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated
////// UPDATE 10.01.2024 //////
I was able to just do a dummy endpoint to populate the csrf token without exposing the token itself like this:-

    @GetMapping("/csrf")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> getCsrfToken()
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

Not entirely satisfied with this approach but it works. I would be more inclined to achieve what we have achieved so far with CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyTrue().

You don't need CSRF protection in your case because:

You need CSRF protection only if you use a session-based authentication, that is because the browser will include the session token on any request made by the user even if it is just a script sent by a malicious person.
you don't need it on the login page because the user is not yet authenticated.

Instead, you must build a login endpoint where the user submits his credentials and gets a JWT token.
after that, you send the JWT token in all endpoint that needs authentication, preferably the header Authorization
in your spring application you need to configure a filter to authenticate the user based on the content of the header Authorization.
you can find more about how to build JWT based authentication in the internet there are many articles about that.
RECAP: you don't need CSRF protection as long as you don't use session-based authentication.
also don't use session-based authentication with react
